# How to filter out string with dot 4 digit number dot and rfa extension?

Tags: c#, if-statement, file-extension

This should be quite straight forward, in dos i can use a *.????.rfa filter, it evens works in windows context search. 
how can i simply do this in C# if conditional?

```
if (file.Extension.Contains(".rfa") &!file.Extension.Contains(".0001.rfa"))
    ...
```

Comment: Do you now, that you can/should answers as an answer? If nothing solves your problem, feel free to ask for more details.

Answer (score 0):

I would combine [LINQ](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397933.aspx) and [Regex](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

```
Regex r = new Regex (@"\.\d{4}\.rfa$");

foreach (FileInfo fi in new DirectoryInfo(@"c:\path").GetFiles().Where(x=> r.IsMatch(x.Name))) {
    Console.WriteLine (fi.FullName);
}
```

//edit: Added the pattern mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30694063/3451056).

Answer (score 0):

You can use this regular expression: `@"\.\d{4}\.rfa$"`:

```
Regex.IsMatch(file.FullName, @"\.\d{4}\.rfa$")
```

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/PL294V)